# Find the smallest Valeriepieris circle

Tags: optimization, greedy-algorithms, average-case

The [Valeriepieris Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valeriepieris_circle) is a circle within which it is supposed that the majority of the World's population lives. I'm interested in general-case and average-case algorithms for finding such a circle.

I'm aware that this can be done in $O(nm)$ and perhaps $O(n + m)$ where $n
$ is the number of pixels and
$m$ is the number of circle sizes, given data is discrete. While finding such a solution is of interest for practical reasons, I'm also interested in algorithms for the continuous case.

#### Generalization

A more generalized form of the problem at hand might be something like...

Given an n-dimensional manifold over which a variable $X$ is distributed, find the smallest n-sphere satisfying the constraint $\Gamma$.

The most interesting average case is the original (human population over a globe):

- Clustering; perhaps we can optimize for a Hopkins stat $H > 0.5$.
- Just a regular old Euclidean manifold suffices.

#### Related Questions

[Find the smallest enclosing circle.](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/89981/find-smallest-enclosing-circle)

Comment: How would you represent the population map in the continuous case ?

Comment: I suppose it would become a piecewise density function of some sort. I'm not sure what the best representation of this on a machine would actually be. Perhaps, it's an array of points with lat-lng and the parameters of said piece of said density function. Or, perhaps it does just become best to always consider some discrete (rasterized version). Idk, that's part of my interest.